# Codeception do not truncate debug output

Tags: codeception

Is there a way to force Codeception to display the full debug output of an acceptance test instead of truncating it?

[image]

I have the `--debug` flag on and I'm seeing output in the console, but it truncates it like this

`I wait for element "//*[@id="whole_subpanel_leads_ods_inventory"]//*/ul[@class="clickMenu fancymenu SugarActionMenu"]/li[@class="sugar_action_button"]/span[@class="suitepicon su..."`

I want to see what's after `su...`

It saves the screenshot and the markup to the `_output` folder, but unfortunately not the full debug output.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output in terminal is truncated to fit into one line.

You can find full step output in HTML report, which is generated when `--html` parameter is used.

Alternatively you could use `codecept_debug` function to log parameter that you are passing to `waitForElement` method.

Evidence that steps aren't truncated in HTML report:

[image]